# Factor polynomial into linear factors with complex coefficients.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Question: A polynomial is given. $(a)$ Factor it into linear and irreducible quadratic factors with real coefficients. $(b)$ Factor it completely into linear factors with complex coefficients.

$x^3 - 5x^2 + 4x - 20$

I factored it using the Rational Zeros Theorem and got the following expression: $(x-5)(x^2 + 4)$. Now, I think this is the answer for the 1st question, but how do I get complex coefficients? I can think of complex factors like $(x-5)(x-2i)(x+2i)$, but complex *coefficients*?

Comment: You are asked to factor it *completely*, so the correct expression is $(x-5)(x-2i)(x+2i)$ which has indeed got complex coefficients.

Comment: Aren't those factors and not coefficients? \

Comment: $2i$ is a coefficient of the factor $x+2i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression 'complex coefficients' was not the best way of describing what they wanted. The better way to phrase the question would have been

> Decompose $P(x)=x^3-5x^2+4x-20$ over the **complex field**.

In which case your final result is what they want.